# cumulative distribution function, threshold, R

Tags: r, threshold, cdf

I have daily values of runoff over a period of one month and one specific threshold. How can I find out on how many days the probability is more than 50% that the runoff exceeds that threshold?

Am I right to use the CDF here? But how can I integrate the threshold value?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with R, except for the fact that you're using it to perform this task. It seems like your question is more about the method to perform this task, which would likely be better answered on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think this is the answer
Try to plot a histogram and see if it's normally distributed.
Calculate mean, sd of your data
plot the threshold as a line (not necessary)
Normalize your plot and using z values for the threshold, calculate the probability of values above this threshold